# How to change default WCF serializer

Tags: wcf, serialization, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I Have WCF service and when I update service reference in it shows "system.xml" in following code

```
 /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18408")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
```

but I want to change "system.xml" to "System.Runtime.Serialization" as shown bellow.

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
```

How can I change this. are there any WCF settings to change this ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It's happened, because project use Document.OpenXml as reference. After removing the reference to the project now it use runtime serializer

Thank you ... :D

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have used special types in the DataContract or OperationContract.  I have got this problem before and the reason was I used DataTable in my data contract.